# linux не видит раздел диска

Tags: linux-mint, диск, раздел

При установке Linux Mint сделал три раздела - под систему,общий и кеш.
Так же стоит Win10 (под днее свой раздел на этом же физическом диске). Проблема в том, что после установке (может раньше все видны были разделы) Mint видит только раздел виндовс и раздел операционной системы Mint. Общий раздел для Mint не виден ни с винды ни с Mint.
Если я загружусь с LiveCD Mint, то этот общий раздел для Mint виден.
Не могу понять в чем проблема. Физически это все один диск.
Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте проверить наличие этого раздела через консольный `fdisk` или через утилиту с GUI `Gparted`. Может быть, просто не монтируется автоматом раздел

Comment: Посмотрел, видит, единственное сумма не бьется, в целом диск на 120Гб, а разбит на 150Гб, как так не понимаю. Что дальше делать не понимаю.

Comment: Примонтируйте этот раздел через `Gparted` тот же, после этого сможете использовать. А под Windows он не будет виден, если это файловая система Windows не поддерживается, например  ext3, ext4ReiserFS, XFS, Btrfs и пр